# JQuery--Stopping .html() value from changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, html

I have a `div` as follows:

```
<div><p></p></div>
```

Thus when I do,

```
var div_contents = $("div").html()
```

then

```
div_contents = "<p></p>"
```

However I have another function that is dynamically changing the content of the `div`, let's say, to `<div><h2></h2></div>`

Thus, my `div_contents` value is changing from `"<p></p>"` to `"<h2></h2>"`

How can I keep the value of div_contents from changing so that I can use it as a final or static variable or something?

Comment: Please paste the code for each function.

Comment: your `div_contents` variable will store the html of your div at the point in time that assignment line ran. it will not change when the element changes.

Comment: I think you ought to read more carefully [the syntax](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

Comment: Hmmm... that is weird @jbabey, because it is changing for me, I'll read the syntax again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div_contents` will only change when you make an assignment.  If the value of `div_contents` is `<h2></h2>`, is is because that was the state of the div when you called `$("div").html()`. If the div changes after that, the variable will retain its value until you make another assignment.

I would need to see more of your code to see what is really going on.

Answer (score 1):

try [`DOMNodeInserted`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted) Mutation event, when a new Node is inserted into the document this event fires and you can update the variable's value:

```
$(document).bind("DOMNodeInserted", function(e){
    alert('New Element: ' + e.target)
    div_contents = $("div").html()
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kTrJE/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem- must have made a mistake somewhere but this is working now.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var has_ran = false;
    var div_contents;
    $(".scenario").bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var flipped_div = $(this);
        if (!has_ran) {
            div_contents = $(flipped_div).html();
            has_ran = true;
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
        flip(flipped_div, div_contents);
        return false;
    });
});

function flip(flipped_div, div_contents) {
    if ($(flipped_div).hasClass("flipped")) {
        $(flipped_div).append(div_contents);
    } else {
        $(flipped_div).empty();
        $(flipped_div).append("<div class=\"scenario-desc\">hi</div>");
    }
    $(flipped_div).animate({
        rotateY: "+=" + (Math.PI) / 2
    }, 500, function () {
        $(flipped_div).toggleClass("flipped");
    }).animate({
        rotateY: "+=" + (Math.PI) / 2
    }, 500);
}
```